# On an attempt to create interesting variants of Firoozbakht's conjecture, evoking combinations of different generalized means

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, inequalities

The idea of this post arises when I've considered simple variants of the known as *Firoozbakht's conjecture* (see this corresponding [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture) or [1]), and comparisons by trial and error with means (if you are interested feel free to do yourself comparisons motivated from the Wikipedia *Generalized mean*).

I've considered the variant, that is a comparison,
 $$\frac{n+p_{n+1}}{n+1}>\lambda(n)\cdot p_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}+\mu(n)\tag{1}$$
where $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime number and $\lambda(n)$ and $\mu(n)$ are simple functions. As I've said in the introductory paragraph I got my comparison by trial and error using a Pari/GP program, from these calculations I've considered $\lambda(n)=\log n$ and $\mu(n)=\log\log n$, and my proposal (below in my **Question**) will be for integers $n\geq 2700$.

The identity $(1)$ evokes a comparison for means because the quantity $\frac{n\cdot 1+p_{n+1}}{n+1}$ is the arithmetic mean of $n$ ones $1$'s and $p_{n+1}$ while that $p_{n}^{1/n}$ is the geometric mean of $n-1$ ones $1$'s and the prime $p_n$. The functions $\log n$ and $\log\log n$ are simple functions that additionally belong to a class of functions studied in Rafael Jakimczuk, *Functions of Slow Increase and Integer Sequences*, Journal of Integer Sequences,  Article 10.1.1, Vol. 13 (2010).

> **Question.** Prove or refute the following conjecture as a variant of Firoozbakht's conjecture:
>
> *For each integer* $n\geq 2700$ *the following inequality*
>   $$\frac{n+p_{n+1}}{n+1}>p_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}(\log n)+\log\log n\tag{2}$$
>   *holds.*
>
> **Many thanks.**

My proposal $(2)$ is true for integers $2700\leq n\leq 50000$. You can see it from the web Sage Cell Server using this Pari/GP program (choose *GP* as language)

`for(n=2700, 50000, if((n+prime(n+1))/(n+1)<(log(n))*prime(n)^(1/n)+log(log(n)),print(n)))`

(you need to wait a minute to see that there aren't counterexamples as outputs of this program), or this other output, it is a line written in Pari/GP, showing the differences of LHS and RHS

`for(n=2700, 50000, if((n+prime(n+1))/(n+1)>(log(n))*prime(n)^(1/n)+log(log(n)),print((n+prime(n+1))/(n+1)-(log(n))*prime(n)^(1/n)-log(log(n)))))`

As was said feel free to do yourself variants in your home if you can to create a more interesting variant of Firoozbakht's conjecture using generalized means.

### References:

[1] *Conjecture 30. The Firoozbakht Conjecture*, Retrieved 22 August 2012 in Carlos Rivera's web The Prime Puzzles & Problems Connection.

Comment: I think that the idea is thus if it is possible to prove or refute the inequality $(2)$ for some $n_0>2700$ using the explicit inequalities for primes, since I cann't find a counterexample. Feel free to add comments/critics about this question, I'm waiting your feedback. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also is welcome comments about if my inequality $(2)$ is interesting or if there are similar inequalities in the literature.

Comment: Due the form of the functions $\lambda(n)$ and $\mu(n)$ that I've choosen by experimenting, the inequality $(2)$ can be written as $$e^{e^{A(n)}}>n^{n^{G(n)}},\text{   for integers } n\geq 2700$$
where the exponent $A(n)$ denotes the arithmetic mean $A(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{n\text{ ones}},p_{n+1})=\frac{n+p_{n+1}}{n+1}$ and  $G(n)$ denotes the geometric mean $G(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{n-1\text{ ones}},p_{n})=\sqrt[n]{p_{n}}$. This is just to emphasize that my  inequality is a comparison of means, in the same way that Firoozbakht's conjecture can be  interpreted in terms of geometric means

Comment: Replacing $p_n$ with $n\log n$ in (2) yields a false inequality for all large $n$. I'm guessing that some improved form of the prime number theorem may imply that (2) is false.

Comment: Hm, apparently $p_n/(n\log n)$ decays to $1$ rather slowly (it behaves like $1+\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}$), so I take back my guess that an improvement of PNT will show that (2) is false.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback, the differences $LHS-RHS$ are very small even for the humble segment of my experiments $2700\leq n\leq 50000$, thus I suspect that maybe some user can to find a counterexample, but the best way to refute the conjecture is provide a convincing reasoning as yours. Thus I am going to wait if there is some answer, feel free to add yourself reasoning as an answer. Many thanks @JoelMoreira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (2) holds for all large enough $n$.
According to Wikipedia (see also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/259997/18698)) $\frac{p_n}n=\log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}(1+o(1))$, so
$$\frac{n+p_{n+1}}{n+1}=\log(n+1)+\log\log(n+1)+\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}(1+o(1))$$
Since $\log\log(n+1)\approx\log\log n+\frac1{n\log n}$, so that $\log\log(n+1)-\log\log n=o\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)$, (2) now follows from:

> Lemma : $\log(n+1)-p_n^{1/n}\log n=o\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log
> n}\right)$.

Proof: Using the prime number theorem to write $p_n=n\log n\cdot(1+o(1))$ we have $p_n^{1/n}=\exp\left(\frac1n(\log n+\log\log n+o(1))\right)=1+o\left(\frac{\log\log n}{(\log n)^2}\right)$. On the other hand, $\log(n+1)=\log n+o\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)$ and the lemma follows.

Comment: Many thanks I'm going to study your nice proof. As I've said if some user wants to try a more suitable variant than mine (a variant of Firoozbakht's conjecture, using  combinations of different generalized means) that he/she feels free to do it.